# Is it possible to rename a community url AND set up a redirect for any of its pages?

Tags: lightning-community, experience-builder-page

Scenario: I have have a couple communities on the same domain and need to rebrand one of them. I would like the URL to reflect that branding e.g., currently mydomain.force.com/***Community*** but needs to be mydomain.force.com/***RebrandedCommunity***. It is likely that community users have bookmarked their groups and even specific record pages within the community. It is also likely that users have historical emails with links to the community and its records.

I know how to change the community's URL, but I know that visiting the old URLs will not redirect to the new community. **Is there a method that would allow me to make sure the old links are redirected to the community with the updated URL?**

This documentation is unclear to me: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sites_redirects.htm&type=5
It is not clear whether it is possible to create a rule that is essentially: mydomain.force.com/***Community***/SomeRandomPage >> mydomain.force.com/***RebrandedCommunity***/SomeRandomPage

...when it could be any site page or a record page. Is there another method that could be used to accomplish this?

Comment: What you may be searching for is the `UrlRewriter` which can be implemented in apex and then that class is configured in the Site to handle requests. I cannot remember if works with both sites and communities or only sites. [UrlRewriter Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_site_urlRewriter_reference.htm)

Comment: @MarkPond, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reframing the acceptance criteria, I found it is actually quite simple to rebrand and avoid breaking deep links.

Given the acceptance criteria:

- The existing community is given a new base URL that matches its new branding (i.e. name)
- New communications all reference the new base URL
- Users' bookmarks referencing the old base URL (including deep links) are not broken

Solution:

1. Go to Setup > custom domains
2. Add a new custom URL for the site that is to be rebranded
3. Select the appropriate domain and set a new path

Result: Both custom URLs (old and new) will work for the site

Limitation: Users are not redirected from the old domain and path to the new one, but this creates potential for phasing out the old URL at a later time and impacting the deep linked bookmarks of fewer users.